# Delay firing socketio socket.on("disconnect") for mac only?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am making this game and at one point the `socket.on("disconnect")` just decided to stop working on macs when they close the browser. It works fine on all windows computers I have tested it on, it just doesn't work on the mac. It does not work on all browsers that I tested on the mac (chrome, safari, firefox) but it works on windows chrome and firefox.

It is frustrating because it worked before and now there is a delay on the `socket.on("disconnect")`